# SF Marketing Cloud connections with Xamarin

Tags: mobilesdk

We are looking at integrating the MobilePush feature of the Marketing Cloud Mobile Studio into a new mobile app we will be building:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_get_started.htm&type=5

We were considering using Xamarin for this build but have not found any definitive information that would lead us to believe this could be integrated for both Android and iOS. Do you know if it is possible to integrate this SDK so we can use Push notifications and geofence messaging if the apps were built using Xamarin but deployed as native iOS and Android apps?